# Error: "Module build failed (from ./node_modules/happypack/loader.js):"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, happy.js

This is the theme I am using for a dashboard project

https://themeforest.net/item/enlite-prime-reactjs-fullstack-website-template/23803960

But getting the following error after installing node modules and executing npm start.

```
ERROR in ./app/app.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/happypack/loader.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:135:10)
    at filename (/mnt/d/Work/Web Development/Websites/enlite-prime_v19/enlite-prime/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:94:23)
    at /mnt/d/Work/Web Development/Websites/enlite-prime_v19/enlite-prime/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:122:39
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/mnt/d/Work/Web Development/Websites/enlite-prime_v19/enlite-prime/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:3:103)
    at _next (/mnt/d/Work/Web Development/Websites/enlite-prime_v19/enlite-prime/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:5:194)
    at /mnt/d/Work/Web Development/Websites/enlite-prime_v19/enlite-prime/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:5:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /mnt/d/Work/Web Development/Websites/enlite-prime_v19/enlite-prime/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:5:97
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the Node v17 which has a different SSL provider. You can either

- install Node v16 via `nvm` and reinstall `node_modules` ([instructions here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating))
- run v17 with the legacy openssl provider:

  - Mac/Linux: `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`
  - Windows: `set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`